# check string for equality with multiple options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a concise equivalent of SQL's `IN` in ruby?
I'd like to check equality of a string against multiple options: `a`, `b` or `c` in one conditional expression.

Comment: Hint: this is not really a string comparison, but a test whether a list of strings contains a given string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `#include?`, but that's the other way round (`[a,b,c].include?(c)`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `#in?`

```
string.in?([a,b,c])
```